# Python Gstreamer for Lion

Tags: python, gstreamer, kivy

I've been working on a Kivy project, and I want it to be able to play video, but I've been having a terrible time trying to install Gstreamer. I tried `brew install gst-python`, but I get the following message, which is fairly meaningless to me.

```
brew install gst-python
==> Installing gst-python dependency: pygtk
==> Downloading http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/pygtk/2.24/pygtk-
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/pygtk/2.24.0
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.8.0... no
*** A new enough version of pkg-config was not found.
*** See http://www.freedesktop.org/software/pkgconfig/
configure: error: gobject is required to build pygtk?
```

Based on the [freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/pkgconfig/) site, I have to clone a repository, but is there a specific location that the repository needs to be in? Is there an easier way to get Gstreamer, like pip, or do I have to go through all this to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why the [official package](http://kivy.org/#download) contains gstreamer and all other dependencies. You should download and use the official package, that way you will not have to worry about installing gstreamer and other required packages.

Comment: I obtained Kivy exactly as specified from their site, and, as far I can tell, it does not include gstreamer.

Comment: What makes you think it's not installed? Open the package and search for gstreamer and you will see that it's packaged. Just make sure you are running your app through the `kivy` script that presets the environment pointing to these dependencies.

Comment: I assumed that it wasn't installed, because when I'd run one of the kivy examples that used video, I'd get that the video provider was ``null``, and I'd get ``ImportError: No module named 'kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer'`` if I ran the ``gstplayer.py`` file

Comment: I've found that my issue is caused by running the program from IDLE instead of through Kivy.app. Is there a specific reason why gstreamer exists when programs are run through Kivy.app but not IDLE?

Comment: yes it's the paths setting done by kivy script, you can open it up in a editor and apply the same commands inside it in your shell before calling idle and things should just work.